# Текст не исчезает в десктопной версии сайта

Tags: html, css, css3, html5, media-queries

При переходе на мобильную версию, должен появляться блок с текстом, а когда переходишь на десктоп версию, как и нужно пропадает блок, но текст при этом остаётся

```
<div class="warn">
  <div class="warn_title">
    <p><strong>Извините </strong></p>
    <p>К сожалению, мы пока не поддерживаем мобильную версию.</p>
    <p>Пожалуйста, перейдите на ПК.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
@media (max-width: 1100px){
  .container {
    display: none;
  }

  .warn {
    display: block;
    background: #fff;
    width: 900px;
    height: 450px;
    border-radius: 25px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 600px 9px rgba(220,220,235,23);
    padding: 10px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: 400px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 50px;

  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если текст остаётся, значит, блок не пропадает. У .warn изначально должен быть задан display: none, чтобы на всех устройствах с экраном более 1100px он и всё его содержимое скрывались.

```css
.warn {
    display: none;
}
@media (max-width: 1100px){
  .warn {
    display: block;
    background: #fff;
    width: 900px;
    height: 450px;
    border-radius: 25px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 600px 9px rgba(220,220,235,23);
    padding: 10px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: 400px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 50px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="warn">
  <div class="warn_title">
    <p><strong>Извините </strong></p>
    <p>К сожалению, мы пока не поддерживаем мобильную версию.</p>
    <p>Пожалуйста, перейдите на ПК.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```